# schema mismatch error in databricks while reading file from storage account

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-autoloader

I have below script which I run in my unity catalog enabled databricks workspace and get the below error. The schema and code worked for my other tenant in different workspace and I was hoping it was same for this tenant. now I dont have time to look into the schema changes. Can anyone tell me what below error suggest. What will happen if I put **.option("mergeSchema", "true")'** in my code below

Error:

> rg.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: A schema mismatch detected when
> writing to the Delta table (Table ID:
> 50a8bd1e32). To enable schema migration
> using DataFrameWriter or DataStreamWriter, please set:
> '.option("mergeSchema", "true")'. For other operations, set the
> session configuration spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled
> to "true". See the documentation specific to the operation for
> details.

Code:

```
table_name= "main.auditlogs.Customer_Logs"
checkpoint_path = "/mnt/_checkpoint"
file_path ="/mnt/topics/audit-logs"
schema = "authenticationMechanism STRING,authenticationMechanismId STRING,environment STRUCT<cdfCluster: STRING,loggerInfo STRUCT<transport: STRING>,method STRING,path STRING,principalProjectId STRING,principalProjectIds ARRAY<STRING>,principalUniqueId STRING,principalUniqueName STRING,remoteIp STRING,requestId STRING,requestProjectId STRING,requestProjectUrlName STRING,requestTicket STRING,sourceCommitHash STRING,timestamp STRING,xHeaderFields ARRAY<STRUCT<key: STRING, value: STRING>>"
(spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .option("ignoreMissingFiles", "true")
  .schema(schema)  
  .load(file_path)
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .toTable(table_name))
```

Is there any way I can ignore the schema and load everything as in the table I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `.option("mergeSchema", "true")` then the destination table schema will be updated to match the schema of your DataFrame - new columns & fields in the struct will be added, some column types could be changed to incorporate bigger data types.

So you have a following choice:

- add the `.option("mergeSchema", "true")` when writing a table, then your table schema will be updated
- use only columns that you have in the destination table, but then you will lose the new columns - just add the `.select(*orig_table.columns)` between `.load` and `.writeStream`:

```py
...
orig_table = spark.read.table(table_name)

....
  .load(file_path)
  .select(*orig_table.columns)
  .writeStream
....
```

You can find more information in [this blog post](https://delta.io/blog/2023-02-08-delta-lake-schema-evolution/).

Comment: my destination table is a delta lake table which i have created in above step without any schema just by running this command "%sql
CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS main.auditlogs.Customer_Logs". Also where do I put .option("mergeschema","true")..I tried in between load and write and between .schema() and .load()..I get the same error

Comment: You need to put `.option` after `.writeStream`

Comment: thanks..another question here which is bit away from the question but my above code is now running for a day and still the process is unfinished. Is there a way i can optimize the above query and run this faster. I couldnt select photon acclreator cluster since unity catalog is not supported there.What more can I do?

Comment: UC and photon are orthogonal things. Photon is just execution engine and works fine with UC…

Comment: but when i create a cluster, its ask me to select Photon acclerator--when i select it, it says UC not supported.

Comment: so my cluster currently running the script, do nt hv photon execution engine

Comment: Just created Shared UC cluster with Photon, no problems... Maybe you use old runtime or something like that?

Comment: in Azure databricks?

Comment: yes, and AWS...